# ViewPager refreshing itself

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Am running in some weird problem. I have implemented `ViewPagerTabStrip` by following the tutorial [Here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpagertabstrip-fragments-tutorial/)

It's working fine and i have implemented Three Tabs.

On the first Page /tab , i am loading the data from server & displaying it in the `ListView`

The problem is, when i swipe to the Third Page & then i swipe back to Second page, the data of the first page is being loaded from the server again.( View of first tab is re-created.)

From the logs, it seems that this is the behavior of ViewPager & Adapter.

When we are on the first tab, it creates the view of second tab/ page as well in background & when we are on the Second tab, it was doing same for Third tab in background & upon reaching to third tab, it didn't created the view for it self(i.e third tab).

But when we swipe back to second tab, it re created the view of first tab as well.

How to solve this ? we can't afford to load the data from server again and again while swiping through the tabs.

I mean is there any way to stop the reload of data (or re-creation of view) while just swiping through tab pages? It should load the data when the whole fragment activity of View Pager is created and not at the time of swiping.

Any help on this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the ViewPager only keeps a certain number of fragments in memory before destroying them- this default number is usually two. Thus, what you have to do is tell the ViewPager to retain those fragments.

The simplest solution is to simply tell the ViewPager to keep three fragments in memory [as follows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29):

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Here are a few suggested answers on how to retain fragments (with more than just this method) and the reasoning behind the default behaviour as well as these solutions:

- [ViewPager and fragments — what's the right way to store fragment's state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state)
- [retain state of viewpager fragments android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451544/retain-state-of-viewpager-fragments-android)

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped- I ran into the same problem and looked around for a quite awhile until this simple solution just simply worked perfectly :D